# Why is the title of my html document red?

Tags: html, css, deployment

I am coding in vscode and the title of the document is red. The code works though. Why is it red?

I already tried closing and opening it but nothing worked. I am a new developer so I could need a detailed explanation if thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few common reasons why the title might be red:

Unsaved Changes: If you have made changes to the file but haven't saved them yet, the title will appear in red to indicate that the changes are unsaved.
File Type: Some file types may have specific styling applied to their titles. For example, if you are working with a file type that VSCode recognizes as needing attention or as potentially problematic (like certain configuration files), it might display the title in red to draw your attention to it.
Configuration or Theme: Your VSCode configuration or theme settings might be causing the title to appear red. Check your VSCode settings and installed themes to see if there are any settings related to tab colors or file titles.
Extension Behavior: Sometimes, extensions can modify the appearance of files in VSCode. If you have any extensions installed that affect file handling or appearance, they could be the cause of the red title.